# wordpress custom admin bar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Hello I am currently building a custom wordpress form using gravity forms that is to populate the gravity form page. I am only able to populate the category, description and title fields in the product page however I am not able to populate the price field on the product page. Is there anyway to populate all the fields on the woocommerce product page by using gravity forms?

I appreciate any insight on this problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the price of product in woocommerce custom loop

```
get_post_meta //function used to get the custom fields in woocommerce
 $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price');
```